# print directory structure present in webserver

Tags: java

I want to know the directory structure of a particular directory on the webserver. I can login through putty (by providing userid and password) but i want to do the code in java in my local system and print the directory structure for the same. I did LS -R in putty to get the same but it is very huge so i want this same to print in java console.

Can anyone please suggest in how to do?

Edit:

Let me explain below is the code for getting the directory structure

```
static void showDir(int indent, File file) throws IOException { 

    for (int i = 0; i < indent; i++) {
        System.out.print('-'); 
        System.out.println(file.getName()); 
    }
    if (file.isDirectory()) { 
        File[] files = file.listFiles(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
            showDir(indent + 4, files[i]);
        } 
    }
}
```

but this prints for my local system. I want this to be work for remote server. I have the IP of server.

Comment: So you want a function that prints a directory tree in your Java console?

Comment: So you want to know how to connect to another machine (that you have an IP address for), navigate to and print the tree of a directory. Sorry I'm not sure how to do this, but I'm sure with the extra information and code you posted here, someone will be able to help! I added you additional information to the original question for you.

Comment: You want to print a directory over SSH? You would need to run some kind of daemon on the server answering requests for directories (after verifying the user sending those requests, of course,) or find some class that would allow Java to use SSH. I'm not aware of any.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Chris Kuehl's comment about SSH-ing with Java, you may want to look into one of these:

- [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)
- [Ganymed SSH-2](http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/)

I would assume (but I haven't looked into it) that with one of these one could feasibly write code that SSH's into a machine, then executes commands on it, capturing the output.

It may be as simple as loading one of those libraries, writing code that connects via SSH to the machine, executes and captures the output of: `cd your_dir`, `ls -R`, then prints it.